# Issue with grunt file when going to production

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I developed my web project using [Yeoman Angular Generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) 0.15.1
It correctly works in test (with `grunt serve`), but I am having troubles with distributing it.
In particular:

- I don't see any `views` folder in my dist, in fact I get a 404 error
  when loading the home page: it should include main.html as first
  content, but it cannot find it:
- style files (main.d41d8cd9.css and style.d41d8cd9.css) are empty
- images are not copied to dist
- languages are not copied to dist
- font awesome is not working

Notice that `translate` filters correctly work.
If I manually copy images and languages folders and copy my css content into the existing files, everything works correctly (but font awesome).

This is my index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
  <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
  <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
  <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/style.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css"/>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
<div class="header">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default" ng-class="{navbarNoBg: $state.includes('home')}" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#js-navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a ui-sref="home" style="color: white;"><i class="fa fa-home fa-menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>

<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-dynamic-locale/src/tmhDynamicLocale.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate-handler-log/angular-translate-handler-log.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate-storage-cookie/angular-translate-storage-cookie.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate-storage-local/angular-translate-storage-local.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/config.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/util/constants.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/util/i18n.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/directives.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

This is my app structure:

[image]

This is the dist folder structure:

[image]

This is my `Gruntfile.js` (I dropped what I considered not useful):

```
// Generated on 2016-06-24 using generator-angular 0.15.1
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

require('time-grunt')(grunt);

require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin',
cdnify: 'grunt-google-cdn'
});

var appConfig = {
app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
dist: 'dist'
};

// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({

// Project settings
yeoman: appConfig,

// The actual grunt server settings
connect: {
  // more code for test and connect
  dist: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }
  }
},

// Empties folders to start fresh
clean: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      dot: true,
      src: [
        '.tmp',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
      ]
    }]
  },
  server: '.tmp'
},

// Add vendor prefixed styles
postcss: {
  options: {
    processors: [
      require('autoprefixer-core')({browsers: ['last 1 version']})
    ]
  },
  server: {
    options: {
      map: true
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
      src: '{,*/}*.css',
      dest: '.tmp/styles/'
    }]
  },
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
      src: '{,*/}*.css',
      dest: '.tmp/styles/'
    }]
  }
},

// Automatically inject Bower components into the app
wiredep: {
  app: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
    ignorePath: /\.\.\//
  },
  test: {
    devDependencies: true,
    src: '<%= karma.unit.configFile %>',
    ignorePath: /\.\.\//,
    fileTypes: {
      js: {
        block: /(([\s\t]*)\/{2}\s*?bower:\s*?(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/{2}\s*endbower)/gi,
        detect: {
          js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi
        },
        replace: {
          js: '\'{{filePath}}\','
        }
      }
    }
  },
  sass: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
    ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}bower_components\//
  }
},

// Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
compass: {
  options: {
    sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
    generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
    imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
    javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
    fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
    importPath: './bower_components',
    httpImagesPath: '/images',
    httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
    httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
    relativeAssets: false,
    assetCacheBuster: false,
    raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated',
    }
  },
  server: {
    options: {
      sourcemap: true
    }
  }
},

// Renames files for browser caching purposes
filerev: {
  dist: {
    src: [
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
    ]
  }
},

// Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
// concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
// additional tasks can operate on them
useminPrepare: {
  html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
  options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
    flow: {
      html: {
        steps: {
          js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
          css: ['cssmin']
        },
        post: {}
      }
    }
  }
},

// Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: [
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
    ],
    patterns: {
      js: [[/(images\/[^''""]*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|svg))/g, 'Replacing references to images']]
    }
  }
},

// The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
// By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
// minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
// to use the Usemin blocks.
//  cssmin: {
//    dist: {
//     files: {
//       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
//          '.tmp/styles/*.css'
//        ]
//     }
//   }
//  },
//  uglify: {
//    dist: {
//      files: {
//        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
//          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
//        ]
//      }
//    }
// },
// concat: {
//   dist: {}
// },
//
// imagemin: {
//   dist: {
//     files: [{
//       expand: true,
//       cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
//       src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
//       dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
//     }]
//   }
// },
//
// svgmin: {
//   dist: {
//     files: [{
//       expand: true,
//       cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
//       src: '{,*!/}*.svg',
//       dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
//     }]
//   }
// },

htmlmin: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      conservativeCollapse: true,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
      removeCommentsFromCDATA: true
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      src: ['*.html'],
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }]
  }
},

// ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
// by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
ngAnnotate: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
      src: '*.js',
      dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
    }]
  }
},

// Replace Google CDN references
cdnify: {
  dist: {
    html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
  }
},

// Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
copy: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      dot: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      src: [
        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
        '*.html',
        'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
      ]
    }, {
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/images',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
      src: ['generated/*']
    }, {
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.',
      src: 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/*',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }]
  },
  styles: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    dest: '.tmp/styles/',
    src: '{,*/}*.css'
  }
},

// Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
concurrent: {
  server: [
    'compass:server'
  ],
  test: [
    'compass'
  ],
  dist: [
    'compass:dist',
    //'imagemin',
    //'svgmin'
  ]
},

// Test settings
karma: {
  unit: {
    configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: true
  }
}
});


grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
if (target === 'dist') {
  return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
}

grunt.task.run([
  'clean:server',
  'wiredep',
  'concurrent:server',
  'postcss:server',
  'connect:livereload',
  'watch'
]);
});

grunt.registerTask('build', [
'clean:dist',
'wiredep',
'useminPrepare',
'concurrent:dist',
'postcss',
'concat',
'ngAnnotate',
'copy:dist',
'cdnify',
'cssmin',
'uglify',
'filerev',
'usemin',
'htmlmin'
]);

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');

};
```